# Tell me the detail of virtual table in C++

Tags: c++

Can anybody tell me about the virtual table concept?

Comment: Google/Wikipedia/etc? There are questions that are best asked at Q&A sites, and there are questions that are answered much faster and more completely by digging through existing ressources. (Edit: Agreed with Rob, voting to close).

Comment: Voted to close: overly broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia's article is pretty good:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VTBL

And if Wikipedia's wrong, then I don't want to be right.